# How can I look for questions at my skill level?

Tags: discussion

Many of the questions here are not quite within my skill level. Apart from looking at each question manually, what techniques can I use to find questions at my skill level?

[Meta tags are considered harmful](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/level-of-question-tags)

Possible approaches I can think of are:

1. Look at the question to answer ratio of users. Generally speaking, if someone mainly asks questions, then they're probably still a beginner. Unfortunately, I don't know how to look at who are the top askers of a whole website, as opposed to a specific tag such as https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/topusers (pun not intended)
2. Check what writing they're using. [Ugly American](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html) Romaji? N00bs. Kana? Slightly more advanced (or diligent N00bs that learnt their kana before learning konnichiwa). Kanji? More advanced again.
3. When I find a question that's on my skill level, look at what other questions that person's asked.
4. Browse the [learning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag.

Comment: Not a full answer, but regarding #1, the [most active tab on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top) lists active users and their question/answer totals.  It's not great, but you may be able to recognize a handful of frequent askers.  (Then again, just browsing the questions on a frequent basis also gives you an idea of who asks a lot of questions and at what level.)

Comment: @Troyen: That helped - for example it gave me a question on why the object particle is written "wo" but pronounced "o", which is something I've been wondering about.

Comment: just my opinion but I don't think there are "skill levels" for language. It's just "language I know" and "language I don't know".

Comment: I'm kinda agreed with @Flaw. Language is not a linear set of skills that you can rate from 1 to 10. It's a mixed bunch of skills of vocabularies, grammars, cultural perceptions, linguistics, oral vocality etc, I know I'm just making the terms up, but the point is that there are many sub-fields in a language that are not sequential one after another. You might be pro in vocabulary but suffer from poor grammar skills, or vice versa. Looking at the tags, and skimming through the title of questions are probably the best bet, IMO :)

Comment: "Generally speaking, if someone mainly asks questions, then they're probably still a beginner." - I felt a bit disturbed by this generalization, as the current top asker in JLU. Although I asked (and am still going to ask) lots of questions, I refuse to consider myself a beginner. Just sayin' :P

Comment: @Lukman You do one answer for every three questions, whereas only Chuck Norris could calculate my Q:A ratio!