# Is asking/answering/commenting in non-Japanese/English language allowed in JLSE?

Tags: discussion

So, the original stackexchange is (what seems to be)[almost strictly English only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/1023130), unless you're posting in language specific SE.

And here I met an other language comment in JLSE, what seems to be Persian according to Google translate.

[image: the comment]

So here goes the post title: Is asking/answering/commenting in non-Japanese/English allowed in JLSE? If not, can we have an instruction in tour or somewhere?

Some other Meta question says that JLSE is a site for English speakers learning Japanese. So then why it's not clearly stated anywhere as far as I can find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole site interface, including the tour, is in English, so I guess it is  reasonable to expect that people use either English to communicate — or Japanese, which is the topic of the site.

I think it doesn't make sense to keep any contributions (comments, answers, questions) in other languages, since they probably cannot be understood — and thus also not moderated — by the majority of the community. We're always offering to help users having trouble formulating their question in English to edit their question to make it more clear.

The basic content of the [tour](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tour) is a fixed template, but in principle we can change parts of it. For example this paragraph appearing at the top of the tour:

> **Japanese Language Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language. It's built and run *by you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about the Japanese language.

We could add a sentence:

> Questions and answers can be written in Japanese and/or English.

Comment: On a different note, I also wondered if we should include a Japanese translation of this paragraph, so I opened a new meta discussion: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2224/1628

Comment: Still, the questioner could possibly misunderstand the site policy(since other site such as HiNative does not limit that kind of behavior), since nowhere does it specify that it limits that behavior. So, I would like to agree with adding that sentence to the tour. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The original discussion (reaching VERY far back... post 22 on meta) is [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22).

As a response to that, there is an entry in our "how should I format my questions?" faq [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/811/29).